# Clear controls Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I have groupbox I want to clear all the control in it , I try

```
public void ClearPanels(GroupBox control)
{

    foreach (Control p in control.Controls)
    {

        control.Controls.Remove(p);


    }

}
```

but a panel remain it , the problem I create the controls in runtime , and want to remove it in runtime

Comment: is there a reason for prefering the loop over `Control.ControlCollection.Clear()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use this which clears all the controls at once without using a loop:

```
public void ClearPanels(GroupBox control)
{
  control.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT , IT'S MY FIRST TIME TO USE CLEAR

Answer (score 2):

Use [RemoteAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat.aspx)

```
while (control.Controls.Count > 0)
{
    control.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

or [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx)

```
control.Controls.Clear();
```